# Windows 7: Packets not going through

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point

I have a simple setup:

A) A Windows 7 PC with a Wifi adapter and an ethernet connection.

B) A raspberry Pi Wifi Access Point

C) A router connected to the internet.

A and B are connected via Wifi.
A and C via ethernet cable.

B has a local network and has the IP 192.168.5.1 with subnet 255.255.255.0
In B's network, A has the IP 192.168.5.31. There is also another compute connected to the wifi (192.168.5.25)

From 192.168.25 I can ping A (192.168.5.31).

Now:
When I do "ping 192.168.5.25" from A, there I get "Destination Host unreachable".
However i can ping 192.168.5.1 from A

Why is that?

EDIT: Of course the router (C) is in a different subnet (192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two subnets with the same subnet address connected to one router.

You have to change the IP addresses on one subnet to use for instance 192.168.7.x